# Why custom exception using Throw doesn't execute next statement, whereas table constraint exception does it

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table with Id smallint  and Code varchar(5) fields , there is an Unique Key Constraint on Code.
There is already a row with 'ABC' in code field in table

I have written following Stored Procedure to insert values to it

```
            ALTER Procedure [dbo].[Insert]
                @Id smallint output,
                @Code varchar(5)
            AS
            SET NOCOUNT OFF;
            IF not EXISTS (select Code from SomeTable where Code like '%'+@Code and Code <> @Code)
            BEGIN
                Insert into dbo.SomeTable (Code) values (@Code)
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
               Throw 50000,'Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint. Cannot insert Code which is already a suffix of existing Code in table ''dbo.SomeTable''.',1
            END
            Select Id,Code from dbo.SomeTable  where SomeTableCode = 'ABC'
```

You can see I've written custom throw exception, this should be thrown when Code is present as suffix of any existing code.

When I test to insert duplicate code using following statement

```
    DECLARE @return_value int,
            @Id smallint

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Insert]
            @Id = @Id OUTPUT,
            @Code = N'ABC'
```

I get the following exception:

```
    Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure Insert, Line 19
    Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_SomeTable_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SomeTable'. The duplicate key value is (ABC).
    The statement has been terminated.
    (1 row(s) affected)
```

And I can see the row in Results tab (select statement executed)

But when I try to insert Code as suffix to another codes in table using following statement:

```
    DECLARE @return_value int,
            @Id smallint

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Insert]
            @Id = @Id OUTPUT,
            @Code = N'BC'
```

I get following error but Select statement not executed and I can't see row in Results tab, why?

```
    Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Insert, Line 24
    Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint. Cannot insert Code which is already a suffix of existing Code in table 'dbo.SomeTable'.
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [THROW on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677615.aspx)

> If a TRY…CATCH construct is not available, the session is ended

You are not using TRY/CATCH so the THROW stops the stored procedure execution.

In general, this payttern is unreliable

- two concurrent sessions can both find `NOT EXISTS` as true but only one insert can succeed. Use MERGE
- the THROW is showing "already exists or exists as a suffix", it is not actually a violation
- no TRY/CATCH

Edit, use something like

```
BEGIN TRY
    MERGE into dbo.SomeTable
    etc

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @errmsg nvarchar(2000);
    IF ERROR_NUMBER() = 2627
        SET @errmsg = 'Already exists etc'
    ELSE
        SET @errmsg = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    THROW 50000, @errmsg, 1;
END CATCH
SELECT Id,Code from dbo.SomeTable  where SomeTableCode = 'ABC';
```

And read [Error Handling in SQL 2005 and Later](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html) completely

Comment: what changes I can make to throw exception as well as execute next statement?